# node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, gulp, node-modules

I'm trying to run npm test on an existing project.I've been getting this error. "node-modules is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file". (working on windows if it's relevant)

I've installed babel, upgraded npm, deleted node-modules installed it again, I tried adding ./ and node in my script file but it gives me an even weirder error.

Here is the script file that gives me this error.
script file:

[image]

If i edit my file with node (with or without the ./)
edited script file:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

I have no idea what's going on (complete beginner, have to work on unit testing for school).
Can someone help ?
Thanks.. (ps : first question here I have no idea if these informations are enough, please tell me if you need something else).

Comment: try just `babel-node --presets es2015 spec/run.js` you shouldn't have to specify your node_modules directory

Comment: Solved it thank you!